# Jmeter throughput vs. threads graph issues

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, throughput

I would like to run a test for 10 threads, by sending 100 requests from a CSV file to a server. I would like for each thread to fire 100 requests sequentially while allowing parallel requests. I have my main sampler and sub samplers for its subcomponents  and another sampler to which i want to compare my results. This configuration results in 7 samplers in general. The problem is that when i try to plot the throughput vs. threads graph in jmeter for 1 user results shows more than 100 transactions/sec values on the y axis. Same thing happens in the "show results in table" listener (i.e., for 1 user it shows 700 samples)   How can i graph the graphs/listeners for only the main samplers (mine and the other) to get realistic numbers.

am I doing the right thing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put all the samples/sub-samples into a transaction controller for each response you want to measure.

Then only plot the graph for the transaction result, rather than for each sample/sub-sample.